# Codeigniter htaccess index.php site down

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, web

Codeigniter htaccess started problem suddenly even when no changes were made to any files. I can access

- www.mysite.com/index.php/controller/method

but when I access

- www.mysite.com/controller/method

it gives a general 404, not a codeigniter 404. Any help is appreciated. The site is down.

Here is my present htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

 #Removes access to the system folder by users.
 #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
 #previously this would not have been possible.
 #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

 #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
 #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
 #request to index.php
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 #This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file 
#Submitted by Michael Radlmaier (mradlmaier)
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>

 <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
 # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
 # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
 # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

 ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: Did really nothing change? That's highly unlikely, check (if you did not change anything) your hosting company and asks if any updates happened.

Comment: I have already asked them they deny changing anything. I made some changes yesterday but the site was working fine for 12-14 hours after that with no problems. I have restored the old version from yesterday but I still get this problem.

Comment: Were your changes in related parts of the website? Do you have logs of Apache and see any errors?

Comment: Have you tried to do any edits to the file? Some editors will mess up the line endings - I once ended up with a javascript file 'condensed' on one line, and in my original file, on the first line was a `//` comment... Also, try commenting out the `RewriteBase` line. And check the Apache logs

Comment: Are you sure mod_rewrite is still installed and your htaccess rules are actually doing anything?

Comment: Man, Elliot Haughin's config really got around didn't it? I see this everywhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case i'm 100% sure your mod_rewrite is not working properly.Also make sure your .htacess file is in your root directory. A have this one working properly on my server may be this will help you :-

```
# rewrite rules
RewriteEngine On

# ditch index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: 2 days of digging around and the problem was with the shared hosting idiots who messed up something. But thanks Sachin to for clarifying.